# Нужна помощь с SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица (wp_postmeta), структура такая:

```
id post_id   key            value
1    11    fromcity_1       Москва
2    11    fromdistrict_1   Садовое кольцо
3    11    fromcity_2       Воронеж
4    11    fromdistrict_1   Коминтерновский
5    13    fromcity_2       Воронеж
6    13    fromdistrict_1   Северный
```

И есть вот такой запрос:

```
 SELECT `post_id`
    FROM `wp_postmeta` AS p
    WHERE p.`key` LIKE 'fromcity_%' AND p.`value` = 'Москва'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM wp_postmeta AS c
            WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
                AND c.`key` = concat('fromdistrict_', substring(p.`key`, 9))
                AND c.`value` = 'Садовое кольцо'
        )
```

По идее, он должен возвращать `post_id`, где `fromcity_1 = Вороклини`, а `fromdistrict_1 = Центр`, но не работает. 
При этом у ключей цифра 1 - `ID`, и у ключей `fromcity_` и `fromdistrict_` `ID` должен совпадать, что я и делаю вот здесь:

```
AND c.`key` = concat('fromdistrict_', substring(p.`key`, 9))
```

Но, видимо, я как-то неправильно использую substring, так как не работает...

Comment: Не делайте так... А ответ на ваш вопрос: 10. [For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Comment: А как сделать?) И у меня сделано все так, как вы дали по ссылке:

    concat('fromdistrict_', substring(p.`key`, 9))
 
    p.`key` = fromcity_1. 

Значит в `substring(p.`key`, 9))` должна остаться только цифра 1.

Comment: Нет. 10. 
 
    select substring('fromcity_1',1) => 'fromcity_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',2) => 'romcity_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',3) => 'omcity_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',4) => 'mcity_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',5) => 'city_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',6) => 'ity_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',7) => 'ty_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',8) => 'y_1';
    select substring('fromcity_1',9) => '_1';

Еще раз. Ваш запрос положит сервер. Не делайте так. Сколько у вас постов? При 1000 постах запрос будет выполняться уже секунды.

Comment: Ну так а как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

У вас паттерн EAV, в котором фильтры реализуются так:

```
select p.id 
from posts p
  left join postmeta pm1 on p.id = pm1.post_id and pm1.key = 'fromcity_1' 
  left join postmeta pm2 on p.id = pm2.post_id and pm2.key = 'fromdistrict_1'
  left join postmeta pm3 on p.id = pm3.post_id and pm3.key = 'fromcity_2' 
  left join postmeta pm4 on p.id = pm4.post_id and pm4.key = 'fromdistrict_2'
where
(pm1.value = 'Москва' and pm2.value = 'Садовое кольцо') 
or (pm3.value = 'Москва' and pm4.value = 'Садовое кольцо');
```

Такой запрос формируется в коде, в цикле по свойствам.  
Это не совсем красиво и не очень быстро (должны быть правильные индексы, надеюсь, в wordpress они есть), но по крайней мере уложится в константное количество запросов. По поводу других вариантов, они, вероятно, тоже возможны, но не факт, что будут быстрее (или правильнее) как запрос, который вы сейчас используете.

Comment: > должны быть правильные индексы

только по `post_id` и неучаствующей `meta_id`

Comment: @Etki, существенно ускорить запрос можно как раз другим индексом, по (key, value), правда он слишком дорогой получается по размеру и скорости вставки. Если post_id индексировать, то будет гарантия фуллскана по posts, тут будет зависеть от объема данных (все-таки блог/форум - это не интернет-магазин с 100к товарами и по 50 характеристик на каждый).

Comment: Я, конечно, имел в виду что у вордпресса по умолчанию только эти индексы, двусмысленно получилось.